# Qty Uses Decimals Magento 2 does not work

Tags: magento2, product, admin, quantity

Our client needs to give the option to the customers to buy certain products in the decimal quantities. i.e. the customers can buy in periods on 0.25. (0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1, 1.25....... )

Enabled the option Qty Uses Decimals from the admin panel, when i go to the frontend and add a point its gives me the following message

> You can buy this product only in quantities of 1 at a time.

Here is the backend for the product
[image]

If you know about patch or any extension, that would help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to

> Catalog > Product > Advanced Inventory

Change value of **Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart** this Option in **Decimal Points** [For ex 0.25] or anything minimum quantity you want to add into cart.

Comment: awesome, was able to make the change. one more thing, how are prices calculated now! .. eg. if i had a product worth 10$, if i add 0.25 qty, would magento calculate it automatically ?

Comment: @HammadKhalid Yes, Magento would calculate the prices automatically when you add that Product to Cart.